# Traffic redirection

Tags: redirect, snort, honeypot

I have set up snort as an IDS on my linux system. Kippo honeypot is installed in my raspberry pi. Now whenever an attack is detected by snort, I want that attacker's IP to be redirected to kippo honeypot. 
How can we redirect malicious traffic to honeypot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have snort in IDS mode, you can't send packets to network from snort, you are totally transparent.

However, I would go for a different process polling log files, and sending packets in log with attacker IP as source and honeypot as destination.

If you are in IPS mode, it's possible to develop an active response with packet adaptation but it could be a little tricky. however, I would go with pooling anyway, and let snort just drop & report about the event.

Comment: Using polling method, how is it possible to redirect traffic?

Comment: It's not exactly redirect, but reproduce. Poll the /var/log/snort (or whatever dir you use for the logs) for file changes, and when snort log a packet, the process reproduce the packet to kippo. If you know C, you can check how does it do barnyard2, but it's easy to do with python&scapy, for example.

Comment: I think this will not let the attacker to interact with honeypot. Do you have any idea to redirect attacker to honeypot and let him interact with it and capture logs in honeypot?

Comment: Ok, I though that it was enough with attacker IP address. if you want full communication, snort & honeypot are after NAT, and you are running snort in IPS mode, you can rewrite packet in DAQ to send it to Kippo. If you know a little bit of C, it's not difficult, I can help you with that. A more snort-style way to go could be to write a preprocessor, but it's a lot more of work.

Comment: It would be very thankful if you helped me solve this problem Sir.

Comment: DAQ using (PCAP, AF_PACKET,...)? DAQ mode (inline/passive)? C knowledge?